# System Information Remotely

Tags: hardware, configuration-management

I want to access system information of remote Ubuntu system using terminal. How should I get system details remotely?

Comment: What kind of system details do you want to get? You can logon to an Ubuntu system using ssh and get in terminal any information that you get locally.

Comment: I want to know System Hardware details CPU, RAM, HDD, HOSTNAME, WINDOWS version, IP address etc. of Ubuntu system Remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`rsysinfo [ host | -v ]`displays  a summary of the kernel statistics of a  particular
       host.
       The output shows how long the system has been up,  load  averages,  cpu
       usage  in  jiffies, pages from and to the disk, the number of interupts
       recieved, and the number of context switches.
       The load average numbers give the number  of  jobs  in  the  run  queue
       averaged  over  1,  5 and 15 minutes, all other fields are appropriatly
       labelled.

See also: [CLICK!](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/rsysinfo.1.html)